# treenodes with tooltip images in c#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on treeview control. i would like to have insert a feature of mouse over, when ever mouse over action takes place on the tree node tool tip for the node should be shown.

how can i add tool tip for the nodes in the treevie control in **windows application**.

thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx TreeNode has ToolTipText property. Have you tried it? You have to set `ShowNodeToolTips` for the parent TreeView to true also!